# HttpClient аналог WebClient'а для отправки файлов на сервер

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient, webclient

Вот пример загрузки файлов на сервер через WebClient, он работает.

Считается устаревшим и сейчас в приоритете использования HttpClient.

Как правильно переписать этот код, но с помощью HttpClient, при этом в async\await манере ?

```
using (WebClient clientSend = new WebClient())
{
   clientSend.UploadFile(result.href, fi.FullName);
}
```